# Validate uniqueness of user_id, friend_id, event_id in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When a user views an event in my app I'm comparing a list of attendees to the user's FaceBook friends and storing any intersections I find in an EventFriends table.

I need to validate uniqueness across 3 columns in the table as one user may have a friend that is attending more than one event.

Any  ideas?

Here are the relevant portions of my models:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :event_users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_users, :allow_destroy => true
has_many :events, :through => :event_users, :order => 'start'

has_many :event_friends
accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_friends, :allow_destroy => true
```

**event.rb**

```
has_many :event_users, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_users, :allow_destroy => true
has_many :users, :through => :event_users

has_many :event_friends, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_friends, :allow_destroy => true
```

**event_user.rb**

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
validates_uniqueness_of :event_id, :scope => :user_id
```

**event_friend.rb**

This table has user_id, event_id and friend_id columns.

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :friend_id, :scope => [:user_id, :event_id]
```